# RSpec NoMethodError when calling should_not_be_valid on FactoryGirl.build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my RSpec `user_spec.rb` one of my FactoryGirl factories seems valid and I can call `should be_valid` on it, and this test will pass (and will break if I put an empty string in the factory `user_name`).

```
describe User do
  it "has a valid factory" do
     # should be_valid works fine
     FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
  end  
  it "is invalid without a name" do
    # should_not_be_valid throws a NoMethodError
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, :user_name => nil).should_not_be_valid
  end
end
```

However when I call the above `should_not_be_valid` on `FactoryGirl.build`, the test fails:

```
  1) User is invalid without a name
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:user, :user_name => nil).should_not_be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `should_not_be_valid' for #<User id: nil, user_name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     # ./spec/models/use
```

When it should instead pass, since a blank `user_name` is invalid.  Here is what I have in my factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do  
  factory :user do
    user_name "Foo Bar"
  end
end
```

And my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :musician

  validates :user_name, presence: true
end
```

How could `should be_valid` be working, but `should_not_be_valid` throws a `NoMethodError`?

I would really appreciate any help!  I am running Rails 4, `gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.1"`, and `gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.3.0'`

Been trying to puzzle this one out for awhile with no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use space between `should_not` and `be_valid`:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:user, :user_name => nil).should_not be_valid
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Syntax error resulting from optical illusion?  I can't see that missing underscore unless I squint out of the corner of my eye...